# No Section in Header by using \twocolumn

Tags: koma-script, two-column, scrlayer-scrpage, scrreprt

The headmark over a Section inside a twocolumn still shows the Chapter.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\clearpairofpagestyles
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}
\ihead{\headmark} 

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document} 
\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext 
\twocolumn[
\section{Section}
\blindtext]
\blindtext 
\blindtext 
\onecolumn
\chapter{Chapter}
\newpage
\section{Section}
\blindtext 
\section{Section}
\blindtext 
\end{document}
```

After the onecolumn command, everything is normal again

Comment: The \documentclass line is missing in your example.

Comment: Thank you for this information

Comment: Reduced the example above, maybe now the problem is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional argument of \twocolumn is set in a box, and the mark can't escape. Repeat it after the box:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}
\ihead{\headmark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext
\twocolumn[
\section{Section}
\blindtext]\sectionmark{Section}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\onecolumn
\chapter{Chapter}
\newpage
\section{Section}
\blindtext
\section{Section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it's easy when you know how to do it. Danke :-)